# undefined reference to `dlopen' since ubuntu upgrade

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

i experience the undefined reference to `dlopen' problems since I have upgraded to ubuntu 13.10 and gcc 4.8.1.

The makefiles are working for years already. the particular call is

```
gcc -rdynamic -o ov_dbutil ov_dbutil.o libov.so -ldl
```

The errors are:

```
libov.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
libov.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
libov.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
libov.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ov_dbutil] Error 1
```

is it a gcc problem?

ov_dbutil is compiled with the following lines

```
gcc -g -Wall -O0 -shared -std=c99 -fno-strict-aliasing   -DPLT_SYSTEM_LINUX=1 -DPLT_USE_BUFFERED_STREAMS=1 -DPLT_SERVER_TRUNC_ONLY=1 -DNDEBUG   -DOV_SYSTEM_LINUX=1    -I../../../plt/include/ -I../../../ks/include/ -I../../include/ -I../../model/ -I../../source/codegen/ -I../../source/builder/ -I../../source/example/ -I../../source/kshist/ -I../../source/dynov/ -I../../source/tasklib/ -I../../source/dbparse/ -I../../source/dbdump/ -I../../../../libml/ -I../../include/runtimeserver/ -I. -c ../../source/dbutil/ov_dbutil.c -o ov_dbutil.o
```

no errors or warnings

Comment: Try reinstalling `glibc` package.

Comment: Can you also give us the command that compiles `ov_dbutil.o`? Can you make sure that gcc command uses `-Wall` and then tell us if there are any warnings?

Comment: replace `libov.so ` with `-L. -lov` and try again.

Comment: i solved the problem by adding -ldl to the linking of libov.so

Comment: @ortang: replacing libov.so with "-L. -lov" did not help

Comment: @stasik how do add -ldl to linking of libov.so?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` as linker arguments.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by adding -ldl in the lining line of the .so you want to link agains, it was called libov.so in the upper example.