# undefined reference to dlopen

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I have one C program which I want to load into my running C program. Following are the snippet

**File : a.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void abc() { 
      printf("This is abc\n"); 
    }
```

**File : mainFile.cpp**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <dlfcn.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

      void *lib = dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_LAZY);
       if (!lib) {
         printf("dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
         return 1;
      }
      void (*f)() = dlsym(lib, "abc");
      if (f) {
          f();
      } else {
          printf("dlsym for f1 failed: %s\n", dlerror());
      }

      dlclose(lib);
      return 0;
    }
```

I am compiling with the following commands

```
    gcc -fpic -g -shared -ldl -o a.so a.c
    g++ -w mainFile.cpp -o mainFile
```

Output:

```
/tmp/cc9fYZaf.o: In function `main':
mainFile.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am compiling in Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc version gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

Please help

Note: I have followed the following references but none helped.

1. [Can you dynamically compile and link/load C code into a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829292/can-you-dynamically-compile-and-link-load-c-code-into-a-c-program)
2. [undefined reference to `dlopen' since ubuntu upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926466/undefined-reference-to-dlopen-since-ubuntu-upgrade)
3. [undefined reference to `dlopen'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183899/undefined-reference-to-dlopen])

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Don't compile c-code with a c++ compiler. `mainFile.cpp` should be called `mainFile.c` to make sure that the right compiler is called.

Comment: @HAL9000 Thank you. Yes, you are correct. I should have compiled using gcc.

Answer (score 5):

The second line — the one which links the executable — needs the `-ldl`, not the first:

```
g++ -w mainFile.cpp -ldl -o mainFile
```

Comment: Thank you PSkocik, Jonathan Leffler. I should have read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html properly first. 

Now I encounter another problem.

mainFile_works.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
mainFile_works.cpp:23:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)()’ [-fpermissive]
   void (*f)() = dlsym(lib, "abc");

When I compile it using the flag -fpermissive, I get the following error

dlsym for f1 failed: ./a.so: undefined symbol: abc

Please help.